# Trouble calling findViewById

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

```
for (String s : chunks) {                                                                                     
    String possibleSquare = "s" + s.substring(2, 4);                                                          
    int id = boardContext.getResources().getIdentifier(possibleSquare, "id", boardContext.getPackageName());  
    ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(id);                                                   
    backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));                                               

}
```

The relevant code is above. It's from a method in a class 'Pawn' that is being called by code in another class 'Chessboard'. Now, findViewById is underlined and AndroidStudio is telling me that it 'Cannot resolve method findViewById'.

I figure that this is because the code doesn't know where to search for the View, but I'm not sure how indicate that it should be searching in my 'Board.XML' file.

Comment: Is Pawn a Fragment? It's definitely not an activity.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a bunch of different imageviews or can you have one imageview and pass different pictures into it when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use R.id.YOUR_ID instead of just the ID.
For example

```
ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id);
```

Comment: I've tried that. It returns the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'id''

Comment: Is the id of your imageview "id"? Can you add the XML to your post?

Comment: No, I have multiple imageViews with id "sXX" where each X is a digit between 0 and 7. id represents each one of these imageViews

Comment: Well whatever imageview you want that pertains to this backgroundImg you need to set the id to the id you have in the XML.

Comment: Yes that is what is happening with the code boardContext.getResources().getIdentifier(possibleSquare, "id", boardContext.getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling findViewById in a fragment, or a stand alone class etc, which do not have the method findViewById. So you need to pass it to the class.

Try:

```
boardContext.findViewBy(R.id.id);

for (String s : chunks) {                                                                                     
    String possibleSquare = "s" + s.substring(2, 4);                                                          
    int id = boardContext.getResources().getIdentifier(possibleSquare, "id",     boardContext.getPackageName());  
    ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) boardContext.findViewById(id);                                                   
    backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));                                               

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking earlier, but it still gives me the error 'Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)'

Comment: Hmm can you post the what is passing in the context please?

Comment: case "black_pawn":
                            pawn blackPawn = new pawn(v.getContext());
                            blackPawn.possibleMoves(1, 0);

Comment: That code is within an onclicklistener. the view V is the imageView in my XML

Comment: Do you mind just briefly posting the parent activity/fragment of what is creating the pawn